# How to getting values ​with multiple key queries in IndexedDb

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I created an ObjectStore named "components" with the code below.

```
var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("components", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
let index = objectStore.createIndex('componentFloorId, componentRoomId', ['componentFloorId', 'componentRoomId']);
```

[The view of the data in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqKSD.png)

Using the componentFloorId and componentRoomId Keys, I can query with the code below.

```
const txn = db.transaction('components', 'readonly');
const store = txn.objectStore('components');

 // get the index from the Object Store
 const index = store.index('componentFloorId, componentRoomId');
 // query by indexes
 let query = index.getAll([floorIdFromCard, roomIdFromCard]);
```

However, what I need is to be able to query with the id key as well as these two keys.

SQL Query Example

```
SELECT * FROM components WHERE componentFloorId="1" AND componentRoomId="1" AND id=2;
```

How do I do this sql query with indexeddb?

Comment: Have you tried creating an index on all 3 properties?

Comment: Yes, I tried. This may be a solution, but this time I need to run the get method using only 2 indexes in some sections. It crashes because I didn't give the 3rd index this time.

Comment: Have you tried creating an index on 3 properties, and also an index on 2 properties, and then deciding which index to query based on whether you have 2 or 3 properties?

Comment: Your solution worked! I can create and use new indexes according to my needs. Thank you @Josh